# how to use a function created in a scene in other scenes as well in corona sdk?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I have no experience in Corona SDK, please help.

I have made a score function in a scene that when selecting the correct answer a `+1` is added and `-1` for wrong answer.

**Q:**
How can I use\call this function in the other scenes that I have created without restarting the score?

```
-------------------score------------------------
local score = 0

local scoreTxt = display.newText("0", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 40)
scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
scoreTxt.x = display.screenOriginX + 700
scoreTxt.y = display.screenOriginY + 37
scoreTxt:setTextColor(2, 2, 2)
------------------------------------------------------
---------------------score added 10-----------------------------

function updateScore()
    score = score + 1
    scoreTxt.text = string.format(" %d", score)
end

local scoretimer = timer.performWithDelay(1, updateScore, 1)
---------------------------------------
---------------------score minus 1-----------------------------

function minusScore()
    score = score - 1
    scoreTxt.text = string.format(" %d", score)
end

local scoretimer = timer.performWithDelay(1, minusScore, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest way to accomplish this is to make a global variable that stores score. Like _G.score = 0.

Then, inside your updateScore() function and minus score you set _G.score the the value you are wanting. Like this:

```
    function updateScore()
      score = score + 1
     _G.score = score --set the score to the global variable
    scoreTxt.text = string.format(" %d", score)
 end

    local scoretimer = timer.performWithDelay(1, updateScore, 1)
   ---------------------------------------
    ---------------------score minus 1-----------------------------

   function minusScore()
        score = score - 1
        _G.score = score --set the score to the global variable
        scoreTxt.text = string.format(" %d", score)
    end
```

Now you can just call _G.score from anywhere and it will give you current score.  I would suggest you use a few score modules out there, namely GGData (https://github.com/GlitchGames/GGScore).

The above approach is probably not the best solution, but for a quick workaround it may work.

Comment: "The above approach is probably not the best solution, but for a quick workaround it may work." - As mentioned, this is not the best approach. If you want the the score to be "saved", between multiple sessions(if you close and restart the app), you will need to look into [data serialization](http://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.html). You could also use something like [SQLLite](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/sqlite3/). Using global variables is generally considered a bad practice. Try to use [modules](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) for data shared between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code to a separate file that you require from each scene. However, there will be a bit of work to do to make this work:

1. If all scenes share the score text box (i.e. the box is in the background stage object) then you will have to modify your code so that you have a `setTextObject(displayObject)` that allows the main scene to create the text object and set it in your required module so the scenes never have to worry about it; you will need a way to decide when the `timer.performWithDelay` should be called, like via `increaseScoreDelayed()` and `decreaseScoreDelayed()`.
2. If each scene has it's own score text box displaying the score, you will have to have a `setTextObject(displayObject)` that each scene calls on `enterScene` event to tell your module what display object to put the score in.

Either way the local score should be in the shared module so that the score is application-wide (all modules use the same score instance).